# Fast hill climbing algorithm that can stabilize when near optimal

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

I have a floating point number `x` from `[1, 500]` that generates a binary `y` of 1 at some probability `p`. And I'm trying to find the `x` that has highest `p`. I'm assuming there's only one maximum.

I know we can do this with simulated annealing but I don't think I should hard code temperature because I need to use the same algorithm when `x` could be from `[1, 3000]` or the `p` distribution is little bit different.

Is there an algorithm that can converge fast to the `x` with highest `p` while making sure it doesn't jump around too much after it's achieved for e.x. within 0.1% of the optimal x? Specifically, it would be great if it stabilizes when near < 0.1% of optimal `x`.

Comment: You're assuming only one _global_ maximum, or only one local maximum?

Comment: Yup, global maximum